# How can I position a logo

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I absolutely love the Andromeda theme for the site that I am developing, however I have to make use of two logos. The site logo in a standard position (upper left) and a logo for a parent site which needs to be positioned at the bottom right of the footer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you're going to change the theme, it is recommended to make a subtheme first so that updates don't clobber your changes. See [Creating a sub-theme](http://drupal.org/node/225125) for more details.

As one option, the theme will have a `page.tpl.php` which is used to construct all the pages on your site. You could add your second image here.

Another way would be to add a block and place it in the footer if you really didn't want to modify the theme directly.

Comment: The blocks in the footer are about 600 pixels wide. I have a copyright notice in one of the blocks. If I put multiple blocks it will look bad and sort of to the middle.

Comment: Had a quick look at Andromeda... A style is being applied to the blocks in the footer. You will need to target some CSS to your block to get it to span the footer. I would say go with the subtheme, but if you don't want to do that then change the .info file and add another stylesheet is pretty safe. Your styles will be separated which is a good thing.

Comment: Alright. I'll give it a try.